# how to call a nested procedure thru jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

Please tell me how to call a nested procedure through JDBC using callable statement.  I want to store (1 string and 1 integer) into a table which is created at runtime.

```
create or replace procedure mytable (
Ptable_name in varchar2
, Pemp_name in varchar2
, Pemp_age in number
 ) is

 procedure myvalues (
   Pemp_name in varchar2
 , Pemp_age in number
   ) is
begin
 execute immediate 'insert into ' || Ptable_name
                || ' values (:emp_name, :emp_age)'
      using Pemp_name, Pemp_age;
end;

begin
execute immediate 'create table ' || Ptable_name
                  || ' (sname varchar2(20), sage number (4))';

myvalues ( Pemp_name, Pemp_age);
end;
```

Comment: Why would you want to create a table at runtime? And what do you mean by calling a nested procedure; you want to call `myvalues` directly, rather than calling `mytable` and having that call the private internal insert procedure? Or do you just want to know how to call `mytable`? Either way, what have you tried?

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is not an error message and doesn't help us help you. Please add your Java code and the error and stack trace to the question so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i have tried calling mytable by (begin mytable(+tablename+,+username+,+age+); end; ) using callable statement but it doesnt wrk.  i am referencing the variable correctly ?

Comment: ok.. this is the java code

public class loginuser 
{
public String tablename;
public String username;
public integer age;
public String execute()
{       

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
try
{

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Gaurav","oracle");
stmt=con.createStatement();
callablestatement cs=con.preparecall(" HOW TO CALL A PROCEDURE ? ");

Answer (score 0):

Working demo:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure mytable (
Ptable_name in varchar2
, Pemp_name in varchar2
, Pemp_age in number
 ) is

 procedure myvalues (
   Pemp_name in varchar2
 , Pemp_age in number
   ) is
begin
 execute immediate 'insert into ' || Ptable_name
                || ' values (:emp_name, :emp_age)'
      using Pemp_name, Pemp_age;
end;

begin
execute immediate 'create table ' || Ptable_name
                  || ' (sname varchar2(20), sage number (4))';

myvalues ( Pemp_name, Pemp_age);
end;
/  

Procedure created.

SQL> select table_name from user_tables
where table_name = 'PTABLE';   

no rows selected
```

Java program

```
    Connection con;
    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:c##test/test@192.168.1.200:1521:orcl");
    con=ods.getConnection(); 
    CallableStatement cs =con.prepareCall("begin mytable( ?, ?, ? ); end;");
    cs.setString(1, "ptable");
    cs.setString(2, "pname");
    cs.setInt(3, 1);
    cs.executeUpdate();
    cs.close();
    con.close();
```

and results:

```
SQL> select table_name from user_tables
where table_name = 'PTABLE';   

TABLE_NAME
-------------
PTABLE

SQL> insert into ptable values( 'a', 22 );

1 row created.
SQL> select * from ptable;

SNAME                SAGE
-------------------- ----------
a                    22
pname                 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, however what I want to know is that if I am taking a user input from an jsp page where user will enter his name (table will be created by that name)along with his age and username (which will get saved in that table) then how will i reference name,age,username in the callablestatement (begin mytable (?,?,?); end;)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by referencing name etc. in the callable statement ? A call to the procedure is like any other procedure call, you pass parameters to it (from variables in your code, or constants - your code must know them before passing them to the call) and then call it. Please explain what do you want to do?, does it mean that you want to read values from the table back into the application ?

Comment: how should i reference ( name, age, username) inside the (begin mytable (?,?,?); end;)

Comment: You use callable statament and setXXX function to reference them. `begin mytable( ?, ?, ? ); end;` has three positional parameters - three ? ? ? (first, second and third). A call to `cs.setString(1, "ptable");` assigns a value "ptable" to the first ? (first parameter) in the call to the oracle procedure (inside begin ... end). A call to `cs.setString(2, "pname");` assigns value "pname" to second parameter, and `cs.setInt(3, 1);` - a value 1 to the third parameter. And, finally, `cs.executeUpdate();` executes the procedure using these three parameters.